# pyzabbix requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 504 error using trigger.get method

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests, zabbix, http-status-code-504

I was using [pyzabbix](https://github.com/lukecyca/pyzabbix) and trying to use `trigger.get` method to get all trigger info, but returned 504 Gateway Timeout exception. It never happened before, when I tried to get all the single host trigger info by specifying the host name using `filter` keyword it worked well. I thought it resulted from the increasing amount of hosts which means large number of trigger it returned. I have about 1800 hosts so far. Any solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

While Zabbix API in general [has performance issues](https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBX-5640), and there are various PHP parameters to control timeouts like [max_execution_time](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time), HTTP response code 504 sounds suspicious. If you are using a proxy (maybe transparent, reverse etc), check the timeouts there and consider hitting the Zabbix API directly.